# React - How to setState for different .map data Arrays?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm building my app. But I have one problem, it's not possible to use setState for multiple API calls using Axios.

I have 2 different URL's one for Fragrances and one for Cosmetics.

The first used to work when I setState on load to the fragrances array.

When I try to use another API call for the cosmetics it says Fragrances is not an Array now.

How can i loop through multiple different API "categories" and how can I set the state for each of these arrays (data)? What am I doing wrong here?

Followed by my code.

```
// Core React
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Axios
import axios from 'axios';

// Constants
import { FRAGRANCES_URL, COSMETICS_URL } from 'constants/import';

// Components
import Fragrances from 'components/Fragrances/Fragrances';
import Cosmetics from 'components/Cosmetics/Cosmetics';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    fragrances: [],
    cosmetics: []
  }

  getCoffee() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('☕'), 1000); // it takes 1 seconds to make coffee
    });
  }

  async showData() {
    try {
    const coffee = await this.getCoffee();
    const fragranceData = axios(FRAGRANCES_URL);
    const cosmeticsData = axios(COSMETICS_URL);

    console.log(coffee); // ☕

    await Promise.all([fragranceData, cosmeticsData]).then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        fragrances: data[0],
        cosmetics: data[1]
      })
    })
    } catch (e) {
     console.error(e); // 
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Fragrances FragranceArray={this.state.fragrances} AppURL={FRAGRANCES_URL} />
        <Cosmetics CosmeticsArray={this.state.cosmetics} AppURL={COSMETICS_URL} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You should use `data[0].data` instead of  `data[0]` which is the axios response object

Comment: After doing this i get TypeError: CosmeticsArray.map is not a function and TypeError: FragranceArray.map is not a function

Comment: Have you tried logging the data to the console before the setState call?

Comment: Nevermind fixed it with:

      this.setState({
      fragrances: category[0].data.entries,
      cosmetics: category[1].data.entries
      })

Now works just fine.. thanks JOnas.